# Should I edit or flag an answer that is an attempt to answer but contains spam?

Tags: support, edits, answers, spam

At first I think that editing is preferred way because after it the answer will become valid, but I am not sure, maybe flagging is important because it will bring moderator attention to the fact that this user is spamming? Or maybe it is better to do both actions?

EDIT: If it is not clear, "editing" here means removing all spam links and such things.

Comment: If it contains spam, flag it. Don't bother editing it.

Comment: See [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/167315) on the Stack Exchange Meta.